# What would happen if a there emerges a pattern of overthrown warrants by a federal judge?

Tags: united-states

Does the mechanism by which federal judges are chosen in the USA consider things like how many warrants issued by the judge were overthrown? Is this type of thing a professional embarrassment for a judge, a blight on his record so to say or is it so common as to not matter to a judge?

I would be interested to know on what basis federal judges are chosen and reinstated and what effect overthrown warrants would have in this process (if at all)

Comment: This varies widely across state and local jurisdictions within the US.  Does your tag indicate that you are asking about federal judges?

Comment: Ok I have made an edit

Comment: I suppose you're aware that federal judges are appointed for life, and can be removed only through impeachment and conviction by Congress?

Comment: No I'm not aware of that

Comment: https://www.uscourts.gov/judges-judgeships/about-federal-judges may be good background reading.

Comment: Maybe I should be made aware of that by having an answer tell me that. The assumption that I dont the answer to the questions I ask is warranted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the U.S. Federal judges are appointed by the president and confirmed by a vote in the senate. There are no professional qualifications required.They serve for life unless removed by impeachment or they resign.  Some have resigned due to scandal. Some have been impeached and some voluntarily retire.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by George White is correct. Federal Judges are often prominent lawyers, and not infrequently have been state Judged before being appointed as Federal judges. The President normally considers their records as a whole before nominating them, and may consult members of the Department of Justice or other advisors. But the President acts on his or her own authority and opinion. Nominees need not even be lawyers, although they pretty much always are. The only check on the appointment is Senate confirmation, and the only check later is the possibility of impeachment  and removal from office, or public opinion which may cause  a Judge to resign. Impeachment  and removal has happened several times, but never yet for "overthrowing warrants".

Comment: How would negligence or just poor job performance factor into these impeachment? Has there been such a impeachment for a judge that they thought was going to be a good judge, but just turned out not to be?

Comment: @NeilMeyer: Impeachment is entirely at Congress's discretion.  But you can see [here](https://www.fjc.gov/history/judges/impeachments-federal-judges) a list of all historical impeachments of federal judges.  None have been for simple poor performance, but there have been a couple for "mental instability" and "intoxication" which are not otherwise crimes.